# clientHeight & clientWidth always zero in Angular & Ionic Component

Tags: javascript, angular, dom, ionic4

I have barcode component, when used it should show a barcodescanner in the correct width and height (the containers width and height). These values are needed to correctly initialize the scanner.

I want to get the clientHeight and clientWidth using a ElementReference in angular. Like so:

```
@ViewChild('scannercontainer') scannerContainer: ElementRef;

ngAfterViewInit() {
    console.log('Container clientHeight: ', this.scannerContainer.nativeElement.clientHeight);
    console.log('Container clientWidth: ', this.scannerContainer.nativeElement.clientWidth);
}
```

Html:

```
<div class="viewport-wrapper" #scannercontainer>
    <div [hidden]="!scannerInitialized" class="viewport" #scanner></div>
</div>
```

SCSS:

```
$card-padding: 20px;
$card-border-radius: 6px;
$card-background-color: #ffffff;

:host {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 250px;
}


::ng-deep .viewport-wrapper {
    display:block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 250px; // height: 100%;
    border-bottom-left-radius: $card-border-radius;
    border-bottom-right-radius: $card-border-radius;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    .viewport {
        display:block;
        canvas {
            position:absolute;
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
        }
    }
}
```

When I check the console log the clientHeight & clientWidth is always zero, so I tried adding a timeout using the setTimeout(); method. This worked, but only if I waited 3 seconds. A zero would not work.

Are there any other solutions I could use?

I tried putting the barcode-component source directly into the page I was planning to use it in. This worked correctly, but I'm really curious why this won't work.

Comment: To get height and width you can use html2canvas

Comment: What is `scannercontainer`?

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pjcdzv this link gives correct height

Comment: @GaurangDhorda I added some extra HTML & SCSS code.

Comment: @GaurangDhorda Your example works, but I wish to get the height and width inside the component instead of the parent page/component.

Comment: which component?

Comment: @GaurangDhorda Inside the barcode component

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jzfmte I cannot reproduce your issue

Comment: @SaltyPotato its not working because , you should not be setting overflow-x: hidden inside the body or should not set height:100%  for that element. ionic for some reason is auto setting height:100%

Comment: Pleae check my updated stackblitz link you can get height form barcode component too.. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pjcdzv?file=src%2Fapp%2Fbarcode%2Fbarcode.component.html

Comment: welcome, I posted same answer too. Please Vote Up and Accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to get height from template to component you can use @ViewChild()...
Complete working example is in this [StackBlitz Link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pjcdzv?file=src%2Fapp%2Fbarcode%2Fbarcode.component.ts)

```
// your HTML file is..

<div style="width:50vw; margin: 0 auto; border: 1px solid red; padding:1rem; text-align:center" #barcode>

     <app-barcode [ObjectHeight]="barcodeHeight" >
     </app-barcode>
</div>
```

// Your Component.ts is ...

```
@ViewChild ('barcode', {static:true}) barcode : ElementRef;

   constructor(private cdr: ChangeDetectorRef){}

ngAfterViewInit(){
   this.barcodeHeight= this.barcode.nativeElement.clientHeight;
   this.cdr.detectChanges();
}
```

// Your Barcode Component.ts is...

```
 height;
  @Input ('ObjectHeight') set heightFromApp(value){
    this.height= value;
  }
```